# Obtain value of URL in enclosure tag from xml feed

Tags: php, xml

This is the XML that I am trying to parse:

```
<item>
  <title>HomeAdvisor finds that there</title>
  <link>http://feeds.inc.com/~r/home/updates/story01.htm</link>
  <description>The company once called ServiceMagic tried to be everything to everyone looking for a service.</description>
  <enclosure url="http://www.inc.com/uploaded_files/image/640x290/getty_475902405_9706479704500113_63918.jpg" type="image/jpeg" />
  <pubDate>Mon, 17 Aug 2015 02:40:00 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
```

This is my PHP code:

```
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
$item = array(
    'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'desc' => $node->enclosure['url'],
    'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue
);
}
```

However, I always get the error:

```
 Undefined property: DOMElement::$enclosure
```

How can I get the value of URL from enclosure tag without any error?

Comment: is $rss DOM??How do you assign $rss variable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `enclosure` is just a child element of `item`, and the `url` is an *attribute* of it, it looks very much the same as the other items. You'll need [`attributes`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnamednodemap.php) to access the attribute:

```
'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->attributes['url']->nodeValue,
```

Comment: Now, I get this error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMAttr could not be converted to string` when I echo this value with `$feed[$x]['desc']` where `$x` is index.